# Как загрузить по ajax 2 разных набора данных в разные id из одного файла?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, пагинация

Вопрос в следующем.
Основываясь на поисковых критериях, по ajax, php файл генерирует кусок таблицы, т.е. её внутреннюю часть между тегами tbody, её я и передаю через ajax в tbody id="t-data" через innerHTML, а после получения данных, в файле закрываются все теги и идёт div с пагинацией, в который нужно передать данные о том сколько строк данных в результате было получено сервером всего, чтоб разбить на страницы и создать структуру пагинации. Вот тут как раз и косяк, как получить через ajax 2 куска кода для разных id? Данные о количестве страниц известны в файле где происходит генерация таблицы. Записать в куки данные нельзя, так как как уже есть отрисовка данных и заголовков страницы. Как я понимаю 2 куска кода для разных id тоже не встроишь, так как получается простыня и её нельзя разбить. Получается  наверное только один выход, генерировать данные и посылать их в формате JSON, а на странице с помощью JS создавать структуру таблицы и пагинации?

Comment: Данные на сервере оформите в виде массива и передайте клиенту. Клиент будет видеть количество элементов и сможет построить пагинацию. Если не подходит, то тогда да, JSON, `{id: id, numRows: rows, data: [ ...someDtata ]}`

Comment: Еще конечно можно отдельно строить пагинацию на php, но лучше JSON

Comment: SwaD - в таком случае придётся выдавать весь массив данных сразу, а я хочу выдавать по одной странице из к примеру 10 записей, а пагинацию отрисовать для всего запроса, например 4 страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы. Действительно JSON стал лучшим вариантом. Делаю 2 запроса, 1 подсчитывает общее количество строк по запросу, а второй делает срез и выдаёт данные в зависимости от страницы. Общее количество строк запихиваю в конце массива перед запаковкой в JSON, а потом отлавливаю JS 'count' в JSON выводе и запихиваю значение в переменную. После этого строю пагинацию и всё готово.